# Trouble selecting proper cases in SAS

Tags: sas

I need help with my SAS code. I have a dataset (test) that have variables yearcase and case. Yearcase is a variable that indicates a 2-motor vehicle crash .Case is a binary variable that indicates each of the 2 cars involved in the crash. I want to create a dataset (test2) that only includes case=1( car that caused the crash) and case=0 (car that did not cause the crash). I want each yearcase (crash pair) to have the car that caused the crash and one that did not cause the crash. I want to exclude yearcases (2-motor vehicle crashes) in which both cars did not cause the crash (case=0) or in which both cars caused the crash (case=1). My code here yields the following output below. As you can see, I still have yearcases (crashes) in which either both cases caused the crash (case=1) or both cases did not cause the crash (case=0). I attempted to use flag variables nocase and bothcase but its not working.

```
data test2; 
set test;
retain nocase bothcase;
by yearcase;
if first.yearcase then case=nocase;
if last.yearcase then case=bothcase;
if bothcase=nocase then output;
run;

proc freq data=test2;
tables yearcase*case/norow nocol nopercent;
run;

Output looks like this:

                        case 
 yearcase        case= 0    case= 1       Total
 201410001        0           2          2
 201410007        0           2          2
 201410015        2           0          2
 201410024        1           1          2
 201410031        1           1          2
 201410036        0           2          2
```

How can I make sure I only have yearcases (2-motor vehicle crashes) in which there is only 1 car that caused the crash (case=1) and another that did not (case=0)? I may need to use flag variables..but i'm unsure how to. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input/output. It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited the post to include sample of output. Let me know if that makes sense or not. Yearcase is a variable that consist of pairs of the case variable. I just want to create a dataset in which each yearcase has a case and a nocase (1 and 1) and not 2 nocases or 2 cases.

Comment: I'm still not fully understanding what you want.  Please provide sample input and what you want the output to be.

Comment: I have clarified my question and input dataset and output. let me know if my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For future data processing questions please clearly state both the **have** data set and the **want** data set.  Additionally describe the variables, their typical values and meaning.  Armed with a good question you will either figure it out yourself before posting, or have high probability of a good answer.

Since you haven't articulated the have (or input) data set, the variables can only be inferred from your posted failed processing code.  My assumption is that there are flag variables **case** and **bothcase**.

**case** might have represented a case id, but **bothcase** knocks that precept out.

Without the input specifics there is no good answer.

You might need some code that uses DOW looping and outputs only one record per group.

```
data want;
  do until (last.yearcase);
    set have;
    by yearcase;
    if <condition-1> then counter_1+1; else
    if <condition-2> then counter_2_1;
  end;
  if <counter_1 logic> and <counter_2 logic> then OUTPUT;
run;
```

Sometimes you will need to 'measure' or 'detect' over a group over its entirety before applying another rule per item in the group.  For those situations two adjacent loops can be used.

```
data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.yearcase);
    set have;
    by yearcase;
    if <condition-detection-logic> then <flag> = 1;
  end;
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;  %* reprocess that same by group through a second input buffer (i.e. set);
    set have;
    if < <flag> based logic> then <flag-2> = 1;
  end;
  if <flag-2> then OUTPUT;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As you suggested,let me clarify the have and want data sets and the input specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses. My question was not well articulated at first. But I have made some edits to clarify the dataset I have and that  want. I have found an alternative solution:

```
 `proc sort data=test;
  by yearcase case;
  run;

  data test2;
  set test;
  by yearcase case;
  if (case=0 and first.yearcase and last.case)
  or (case=1 and last.yearcase and first.case);
  run;`
  This gives me a dataset test2 that consist of 1 case (case=1) and 1 
  noncase (case=0) per each YEARCASE.

  `proc freq data=test2;
   tables yearcase*case/norow nocol nopercent;
   run;`

   output looks like this:

                          case 
   yearcase        case= 0    case= 1       Total
   201410024        1           1          2
   201410031        1           1          2
   201410040        1           1          2
   201410044        1           1          2
   201410051        1           1          2
   201410052        1           1          2
```

I am still curious of alternative methods using retain statement and/or 
flag variables as in my initial code before.

Thanks